# Redirection loop problem at facebook iframe application

Tags: redirect, loops, facebook

I do IFrame application for facebook.

Problem is: any link inside it causes redirect loop

Link is: `http://mydomain/mypage?fb_sig=[what I got from $_GET['fb_sig']]`
(to test I link to the *same* page as my loaded canvas is loaded from)

when I click on it, my server returns:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=5dc632fcef992470341178f492f79b93&v=1.0&next=http%3A%2F%2Fthiismydomain%2Ffacebook%2F%3Ffb_sig%3D96a5c47f133eadcfbba4abf82e5311e0%26page%3D1";
</script>
```

then it goes to corresponding page, and facebook returns

```
Location: http://thisismydomain/facebook/?fb_sig=96a5c47f133eadcfbba4abf82e5311e0&page=1&auth_token=ce4cf4968f91cace5b3e915f5b658984
```

then, my server replies with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=5dc632fcef992470341178f492f79b93&v=1.0&next=http%3A%2F%2Fthisismydomain%2Ffacebook%2F%3Ffb_sig%3D96a5c47f133eadcfbba4abf82e5311e0%26page%3D1%26auth_token%3Dce4cf4968f91cace5b3e915f5b658984";
</script>
```

and back, facebook replies:

```
Location: http://thisismydomain/facebook/?fb_sig=96a5c47f133eadcfbba4abf82e5311e0&page=1&auth_token=ce4cf4968f91cace5b3e915f5b658984&auth_token=77df653b7949ca39c1a226c82cce8add
```

and it goes on and one without end.

Should I say that this redirect responce from my server is generated automately (most probaby my facebook php lib)

I have no more ideas why this happends. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, where getSession() returned nothing, and thus sending me out on an infinite redirect loop. I solved it by enabling OAuth 2.0 in the settings for the application, as stated here:

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=64656

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you recognize the problem, here is the solution:

fb_sig is not the only param to be passed manually. Whole fb_sig* should be passed. Read more at this beautiful page http://www.foobots.net/breakouts.html